# SSH - buffer_get_ret: trying to get more bytes 4 than in buffer 0

Tags: ssh

I am trying to make a tunnel.

When I run command

```
ssh [user]@[host] -p [port] -L [localport]:[ip]:[port2] -N -vv -y -i /home/glab/.ssh/id_rsa
```

the tunnel starts. Bu the problem is that it after some time stops working.

So then I found out that I need autossh. Tried with this, then tried with supervisor. Nothing helped.

In the var/log/syslog file I see lot of logs, and the first lives which come are:

```
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost autossh[17521]: starting ssh (count 8)
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost autossh[17521]: ssh child pid is 17541
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: debug1: Connecting to [ipaddress] [ipaddress] port [port].
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: debug1: Connection established.
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: error: buffer_get_ret: trying to get more bytes 4 than in buffer 0
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: error: buffer_get_string_ret: cannot extract length
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: error: key_from_blob: can't read key type
Oct 21 07:40:01 localhost /usr/bin/ssh[17541]: error: key_read: key_from_blob \n failed
```

I search what this error means:

http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/ssh-error-trying-to-get-more-bytes-4-than-in-buffer-0

> The problem is actually a corrupt line in a users
>   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. This user had copy/pasted a new key into
>   his authorized_keys file and it had a newline after the ssh-rsa.
>   Strangely enough, people were still able to authenticate if their key
>   was above the corrupted line. Users whose key was listed below the
>   corrupt line were not able to log in.

There is no authorized_keys file in my .ssh directory. But also one comment says that this problem can be because known_hosts have new line at end of file.

Then I check if there is new line:

```
cat -A known_hosts
```

There I saw $ sign, I am not sure, maybe this means new line, maybe not. But when running without -A parameter there is no $ sign.

I tried running

```
truncate -s $(($(stat -c '%s' known_hosts)-1)) foo
```

to remove new line as there is written: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365155/removing-a-newline-character-at-the-end-of-a-file

but did not help.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found out that in remote server file authorized_keys was bad - it had multiple lines for one key

https://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/IT/index.php/SSH_Keys:authorized_keys

Not sure why it was so. After removed line endings where they had not be, problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

For me `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on my local system was bad. I deleted it and then reconnected to all the servers without issue.

Comment: Move it aside instead of deleting it right away.